# Unable to execute "heroku create"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have just installed heroku and plan to use it with rails on Ruby. However, when I run `"heroku create"` command I get this:

```
 hadoop@master:~/rails_projects/first_app> gem install heroku
Successfully installed heroku-2.16.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for heroku-2.16.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for heroku-2.16.3...
hadoop@master:~/rails_projects/first_app> heroku -v
/home/hadoop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)
    from /home/hadoop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/hadoop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-2.16.3/lib/heroku/command/run.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hadoop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/hadoop/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/hadoop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-2.16.3/lib/heroku/command.rb:14:in `block in load'
    from /home/hadoop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-2.16.3/lib/heroku/command.rb:13:in `each'
    from /home/hadoop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-2.16.3/lib/heroku/command.rb:13:in `load'
    from /home/hadoop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/heroku-2.16.3/bin/heroku:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hadoop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
    from /home/hadoop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
hadoop@master:~/rails_projects/first_app
```

Is there something wrong with versions I am using?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is with RVM and readline - checkout

https://rvm.io/packages/readline/